# nServiceBus distributors hanging

Tags: garbage-collection, msmq, nservicebus, windbg

When running a distributor that is relatively busy with 5+ workers from time to time the service stops processing messages.

NServiceBus version is 3.3.8 with a few backports of fixes from 4.x (regarding MessagePropertyFilters, Locking regarding ClearAvailabilityForWorkers and a few minor issues) the source code is available here:

https://github.com/PeterLehmann/NServiceBus/tree/undoWfpNameChange

Analyzing a hanging service with WinDBG shows that most threads is waiting for memory allocation or freeing like this:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.InternalFree(IntPtr)
System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.Free()
System.Messaging.Interop.MessagePropertyVariants.Unlock()
System.Messaging.MessageQueue.ReceiveCurrent(System.TimeSpan, Int32, System.Messaging.Interop.CursorHandle, System.Messaging.MessagePropertyFilter, System.Messaging.MessageQueueTransaction, System.Messaging.MessageQueueTransactionType)
System.Messaging.MessageQueue.Peek(System.TimeSpan)
NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.Msmq.MsmqMessageReceiver.HasMessage()
NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Transactional.TransactionalTransport.HasMessage()
NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Transactional.TransactionalTransport.Process()
NServiceBus.Utils.WorkerThread.Loop()
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)
```

and

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.InternalAlloc(System.Object, System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandleType)
System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle..ctor(System.Object, System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandleType)
System.Messaging.Interop.MessagePropertyVariants.Lock()
System.Messaging.MessageQueue.ReceiveCurrent(System.TimeSpan, Int32, System.Messaging.Interop.CursorHandle, System.Messaging.MessagePropertyFilter, System.Messaging.MessageQueueTransaction, System.Messaging.MessageQueueTransactionType)
System.Messaging.MessageQueue.Peek(System.TimeSpan)
NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.Msmq.MsmqMessageReceiver.HasMessage()
NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Transactional.TransactionalTransport.HasMessage()
NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Transactional.TransactionalTransport.Process()
NServiceBus.Utils.WorkerThread.Loop()
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)
```

We have multiple threads with the above two stacks all seem to be hanging and messages isn't being processed. And then we have single thread also waiting for InternalAlloc that is in the middle of Raven communication

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.InternalAlloc(System.Object, System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandleType)
System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle..ctor(System.Object, System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandleType)
System.Net.SafeDeleteContext.InitializeSecurityContext(System.Net.SecurDll, System.Net.SafeFreeCredentials ByRef, System.Net.SafeDeleteContext ByRef, System.String, System.Net.ContextFlags, System.Net.Endianness, System.Net.SecurityBuffer, System.Net.SecurityBuffer[], System.Net.SecurityBuffer, System.Net.ContextFlags ByRef)
System.Net.SSPIAuthType.InitializeSecurityContext(System.Net.SafeFreeCredentials, System.Net.SafeDeleteContext ByRef, System.String, System.Net.ContextFlags, System.Net.Endianness, System.Net.SecurityBuffer[], System.Net.SecurityBuffer, System.Net.ContextFlags ByRef)
System.Net.SSPIWrapper.InitializeSecurityContext(System.Net.SSPIInterface, System.Net.SafeFreeCredentials, System.Net.SafeDeleteContext ByRef, System.String, System.Net.ContextFlags, System.Net.Endianness, System.Net.SecurityBuffer[], System.Net.SecurityBuffer, System.Net.ContextFlags ByRef)
System.Net.NTAuthentication.GetOutgoingBlob(Byte[], Boolean, System.Net.SecurityStatus ByRef)
System.Net.NTAuthentication.GetOutgoingBlob(System.String)
System.Net.NegotiateClient.DoAuthenticate(System.String, System.Net.WebRequest, System.Net.ICredentials, Boolean)
System.Net.NegotiateClient.Authenticate(System.String, System.Net.WebRequest, System.Net.ICredentials)
System.Net.AuthenticationManager.Authenticate(System.String, System.Net.WebRequest, System.Net.ICredentials)
System.Net.AuthenticationState.AttemptAuthenticate(System.Net.HttpWebRequest, System.Net.ICredentials)
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmitForAuth()
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmit(System.Exception ByRef)
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.DoSubmitRequestProcessing(System.Exception ByRef)
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.ProcessResponse()
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponse(System.Net.CoreResponseData)
System.Net.ConnectStream.ProcessWriteCallDone(System.Net.ConnectionReturnResult)
System.Net.ConnectStream.CallDone(System.Net.ConnectionReturnResult)
System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean)
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndSubmitRequest()
System.Net.Connection.SubmitRequest(System.Net.HttpWebRequest, Boolean)
System.Net.ServicePoint.SubmitRequest(System.Net.HttpWebRequest, System.String)
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SubmitRequest(System.Net.ServicePoint)
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadStringInternal(System.Func`1<System.Net.WebResponse>)
Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadResponseString()
Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadResponseJson()
Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.DirectCommit(System.Guid, System.String)
Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient+<>c__DisplayClass5b.<Commit>b__5a(System.String)
Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.TryOperation[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](System.Func`2<System.String,System.__Canon>, System.String, Boolean, System.__Canon ByRef)
Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.ExecuteWithReplication[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](System.String, System.Func`2<System.String,System.__Canon>)
Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.Commit(System.Guid)
Raven.Client.Document.DocumentSession.Commit(System.Guid)
Raven.Client.Document.RavenClientEnlistment.Commit(System.Transactions.Enlistment)
System.Transactions.Oletx.OletxEnlistment.CommitRequest()
...
```

We have tried variations of Concurrent and Servermode garbage collection and it looks like the issue happend when Garbage Collection is taking place but only sometimes, othertimes we see GC running perfectly and normal throughput isn't affected.

I checked to see if something was blocking the finalizer but it doesn't seem to be the case, did some digging to find if something in the memoryallocation/deallocation could deadlock but doesn't seem to be able to find anything (I could dig deeper here but would like some input first).

Currently operations is restarting the services when this happens however even this fails sometimes and services get stuck in "Stopping" state sometimes and have to be killed hard to get them to start processing again.

So have anyone else experienced hanging services with nServiceBus 3.3.8?

Comment: It looks like the issue is around reading the message properties, some kind of race condition/memory leak... 

did you try to run this on the released version of 3.3.8?


Is it only reproducible under load?

Can you reproduce this in an integration test?

Comment: Its only reproducible under load and happens infrequently so we had no success in making an integration test or load test to consistently reproduce. We have had it running with a released version of 3.3.8 with exactly the same issue.

Comment: Can you try it with the latest version of NSB?

Comment: Unfortunately thats not an option currently for political reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to answer my own question, we were running .NET 4.0.30319 on the system after upgrading to .NET 4.5.1 the above problem seem to have vanished.

I suspect that there has been some updates regarding memory-handling and garbage collection that has solved the issue.